# Checking null on the find result and access a property value without a temp variable

Tags: c#, refactoring, operators

In the below line of code

```
string hostid = results.Find(c => c.HostType == 2) != null ? results.Find(c => c.HostType == 2).HostId.ToString() : string.Empty;
```

Here if I have to avoid the find two times, I have to assign the find result to a temp variable and use that. But I dont want to create a temp variable just only for this line of code. 
Is there a better way to refactor this line so that I can avoid doing find two times?

Comment: How about if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(myString)) ?

Comment: What is wrong with temporary variable. It will be created any way in your current code. With variable your code wil be much more readable, maintainable and effective

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using the null-conditional (C# 6.0) `?.` and null-coalescing `??` operators:

```
string hostid = results.Find(c => c.HostType == 2)?.HostId?.ToString() ?? string.Empty;
```

---

Explanation/Breakdown:

- The null-conditional operator `?.` is a short-form operator for the following:

  ```
  var foo = results.Find(c => c.HostType == 2);

  if (foo != null)
  {
       foo.  /* something... */
  }
  ```
- The null-coalescing `??` operator is equivalent to performing a null-check inside a ternary expression (`x != null ? x : ...etc..`):

  ```
  var blah = results.Find(c => c.HostType == 2)?.HostId?.ToString();

  var hostid = (blah != null) ? blah : string.Empty;
  ```

Answer (score 0):

> But I dont want to create a temp variable just only for this line of code. Is there a better way to refactor this line so that I can avoid doing find two times?

Define *better*. If by better you mean a less readable/mantainable one liner, then yes, Ben Cottrell's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41515287/767890) is one way, there's probably more. Benefits? None that I see.

Me? I'd go for the temp any time, creating a temporary variable is cheap as dirt.

```
var host = results.Find(c => c.HostType == 2);
var hostId = host == null ? String.Empty : host.HostId.ToString();
```

Dumb simple code is, in the long road, the cheapest code, why would you want it any other way?

Comment: I dont think Ben Cottrell's answer is less readable unless you are unaware of the operator. Once you are used with the operator I think the intention of the developer on what he is trying to do is clear with the one liner. Especially when there is a case I have multiple lines similar to this in a method I would prefer this one liner instead of creating temp variables for each one of them.